# Passing Data from one view controller to another (Image)

Tags: swift

Error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Destination Controller

```
var getImage = UIImage()
var name = String()
var gender = String()
var house = String()
var ancestry = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = (charData.image)as! UIImage
    nameLabel.text! = name
    houseLabel.text! = house

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Source Controller

```
var charactersData = [Character]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
}

func loadData()
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        Alamofire.request("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters").responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            (response) in
            switch response.result
            {
            case.success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                json.array?.forEach({
                    (character) in
                    let character = Character(name: character["name"].stringValue, house:character["house"].stringValue,image:character["image"].stringValue, gender: character["gender"].stringValue, ancestry: character["ancestry"].stringValue)
                    self.charactersData.append(character)
                })
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return charactersData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CharTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = "Name: " +  charactersData[indexPath.row].name
    cell.houseLabel.text = "House: " + charactersData[indexPath.row].house

    if let imageURL = URL(string: self.charactersData[indexPath.row].image) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.charImageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let hpc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CharDetails") as? CharDetailsViewController
    hpc?.getImage =  (charactersData[indexPath.row].image) as! UIImage
    hpc?.name = charactersData[indexPath.row].name
    hpc?.house = charactersData[indexPath.row].house
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hpc!, animated: true)
}
```

Im trying to pass an image to another controller but it seems im getting that error, could someone kindly help me. All the other data like name and house is passing properly other than the image. Kindly please let me know where to make changes

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get answers fast, try editing your question to clarify your problem description. Usually you should put your problem description before your code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The website tour helps!

Comment: You shouldn't receive an object from another view controller with its viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = getimage   // change this in view did load method
}
```

Comment: I have put that but now it gives me this error - Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage' - Would you be knowing how to rectify that error?

Comment: may be you are getting a String URL from API convert this URL to UIImage firstly then assign to variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong(this is not UIImage, this is URL string so you can use this url string to download the image):

```
hpc?.getImage =  (charactersData[indexPath.row].image) as! UIImage
```

Please replace UIImage to String because this is not UIImage, This is String URL to download the image

So For this You have to change `getImage` variable UIImage to String and pass this String to this variable

```
var getImage = String()

hpc?.getImage =  (charactersData[indexPath.row].image) as! String
```

After that again download this image from URL in another controller but this way is not good so you to follow below way:

**Or**

You have another option like when you download the image than save it `Character` `Struct` and pass it when `didselect`

Process:

1. Add a new variable like image in Character Struct/Model
2. Assign downloaded image when API call in the Struct/Model
3. And pass this image to another controller when `didSelect`